# Twitter bootstrap scrollable modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap for a project I am working on.

I have a modal window that has a somewhat longer form in it and I didn't like that when the window got too small the modal didn't scroll (if just disappeared off my page which isn't scrollable).

To fix this I used the following css

```
.modal {
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height:90%;
    margin-top:-45%;
}
```

This works exactly the way I want it to in Chrome (that is, the form is full size when the window is big enough, but as the window shrinks the modal shrinks and becomes scrollable). The problem is that in IE the modal is off the screen. Does anyone have a better solution to this problem?

My example can be found at tinyhousemap.com (click 'Add an Entry to the map' in the navigation window for the modal to appear)

Thanks

Comment: I found and been using this solution. It's very slick in how it allows only the bootstrap modal to scroll and not the background content. https://github.com/aroc/Bootstrap-Scroll-Modal

Answer (score 137):

How about the below solution? It worked for me. Try this:

```
.modal .modal-body {
    max-height: 420px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Details:

1. remove `overflow-y: auto;` or `overflow: auto;` from .modal class  (important)
2. remove `max-height: 400px;` from `.modal` class (important)
3. Add `max-height: 400px;` to .modal .modal-body (or what ever, can be `420px` or less, but would not go more than `450px`)
4. Add `overflow-y: auto;` to `.modal .modal-body`

Done, only body will scroll.

Comment: I got this far on my own but really wanted it to be as tall as the window permits, rather than lowest common denominator. But specifying `max-height: 80%;` doesn't work, it expands instead of scrolling. Do I have to use resize events to adjust `$(".modal")[0].style.maxHeight` ?

Answer (score 18):

I´ve done a tiny solution using only jQuery.

First, you need to put an additional class to your `<div class="modal-body">` I called "ativa-scroll", so it becomes something like this:

`<div class="modal-body ativa-scroll">`

So now just put this piece of code on your page, near your JS loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(ajustamodal);
  $(window).resize(ajustamodal);
  function ajustamodal() {
    var altura = $(window).height() - 155; //value corresponding to the modal heading + footer
    $(".ativa-scroll").css({"height":altura,"overflow-y":"auto"});
  }
</script>
```

I works perfectly for me, also in a responsive way! :)

Comment: Great solution, but I would change height to max-height

Comment: Also, you could use $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){}); to trigger the sizing function. This will calculate the height only as needed, not on every resize and load. You just need to check within the event's function if the current modal utilizes the custom scroll height before calculating/applying the css. i.e.  var scrollModal = $('.modal-body.modal-scroll',this); if(scrollModal.length) ...

Comment: is this for bootstrap 2 or 3?

Answer (score 18):

```
/* Important part */
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This works for Bootstrap 3 without JS code and is responsive.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925835/1145134)

Comment: is that bootstrap 2 or 3? question was most likely posted for bootstrap 2

Comment: @spy this is for bootstrap 3

Answer (score 8):

Try and override bootstrap's:

```
 .modal {
position: fixed;
```

With:

```
.modal {
position: absolute;
```

It worked for me.

Comment: It causes alignment issue on IPad

Answer (score 4):

I also added

```
.modal { position: absolute; }
```

to the stylesheet to allow the dialog to scroll, but if the user has moved down to the bottom of a long page the modal can end up hidden off the top of the visible area.

I understand this is no longer an issue in bootstrap 3, but looking for a relatively quick fix until we upgrade I ended up with the above plus calling the following before opening the modal

```
$('.modal').css('top', $(document).scrollTop() + 50);
```

Seems to be happy in FireFox, Chrome, IE10 8 & 7 (the browsers I had to hand)

Answer (score 1):

Your modal is being hidden in firefox, and that is because of the negative margin declaration you have inside your general stylesheet:

```
.modal {
    margin-top: -45%; /* remove this */
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Remove the negative margin and everything works just fine.

Comment: Removing the margin-top improved the modal so that it isn't as far off the screen in IE, but now it is only centered (vertically) on the screen at a specific window size. All other sizes the modal overflows off the top or bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Dandotnet the modal positions itself 50% from the top of the window automatically, you can overwrite that with something lower like 10%, but if you added a negative value it will just go off the screen like it does in IE. By the way, the same happens in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

In case of using `.modal {overflow-y: auto;}`, would create additional scroll bar on the right of the page, when *body* is already overflowed.

The work around for this is to remove *overflow* from the *body* tag temporarily and set modal *overflow-y* to *auto*.

#### Example:

```
$('.myModalSelector').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

        // Store initial body overflow value
        _initial_body_overflow = $('body').css('overflow');

        // Let modal be scrollable
        $(this).css('overflow-y', 'auto');
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');


    }).on('hide.bs.modal', function () {

        // Reverse previous initialization
        $(this).css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
        $('body').css('overflow', _initial_body_overflow);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with @grenoult's CSS solution (which does work, mostly), is that it is fully responsive and on mobile when the keyboard pops up (i.e. when they click in an input in the modal dialog) the screen size changes and the modal dialog's size changes and it can hide the input they just clicked on so they can't see what they are typing.

The better solution for me was to use jquery as follows:

```
$(".modal-body").css({ "max-height" : $(window).height() - 212, "overflow-y" : "auto" });
```

It isn't responsive to changing the window size, but that doesn't happen that often anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this by using the "vh" metric with max-height on the .modal-body element. 70vh looked about right for my uses. Then set the overflow-y to auto so it only scrolls when needed.

```
.modal-body {
   overflow-y: auto;
   max-height: 70vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of this will work as expected.. The correct way is to change position: fixed to position: absolute for .modal class

Comment: what do you base your conclusion on ?