# How to put scroll bar only for modal-body?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following element:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;" > 
        <div class="modal-content"> 
            <div class="modal-header"> 
                <h3 class="modal-title"></h3> 
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-body"></div> 
            <div class="modal-footer"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

It shows modal dialog something like this, basically, it puts scroll bar around entire `modal-dialog` and not `modal-body` that contains the content I am trying to display.

The image looks something like this:

[image]

How do I get a scroll bar around `modal-body` only?

I have tried assigning `style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height:85%;  margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom:50px;"` to `modal-body` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please give a working sample to give you better help, you can use http://www.bootply.com/new to do it.

Comment: Next, allow optional fluid header and footer blocks inside modal so that just the body scrolls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173969/calculate-modal-scrollable-body-height-base-on-fluid-modal-header-and-footer-hei

Answer (score 418, accepted):

You have to set the `height` of the `.modal-body` in and give it `overflow-y: auto`. Also reset `.modal-dialog` overflow value to `initial`.

See the working sample:

http://www.bootply.com/T0yF2ZNTUd

```
.modal{
    display: block !important; /* I added this to see the modal, you don't need this */
}

/* Important part */
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works great. May be something is not clear to me in css. I tried assigning modal-body max-height:65% that doesn't work. The solution you provided works only if I assign fixed height to modal-body. Is there no way to say modal-dialog takes 85% of window and modal-body should occupy say 90% of modal-dialog? But again solution you provided works for me, for now. Thanks!

Comment: @SubodhNijsure Sorry for the late response. You can't set the height in % because that will mean a % of its parent, in this case the parent is .modal-content and its height depends on its children. That's why it won't work unless you set one of them heights. Either you set .modal-content height or set .modal-body height. If you set .modal-content height then you will be able to set the height of .modal-body in % and it will be a % of its parent so you if you set it less than 100% there will be blank space at the bottom, since you are not filling all .modal-content 's height.

Comment: Keep in mind that CSS's `initial` keyword does not work for Internet Explorer, though it does work for Edge.

Comment: @trysis Yes, you are right. For IE you have to manually set the initial value.

Comment: just a little pointer: instead of "height 250px" which could look ugly on some phones that are only 230px height, or less with navbar in landscape: just use `max-height: 80vh;` that is 80% of total viewport height and only for max height, not if it is a small popup

Comment: works fine, but after closing the modal, the links on the 'parent' window aren't clickable anymore... solved with following code:     
.modal .modal-body {
        max-height: 420px;
        overflow-y: auto;
}

Comment: How do you make the scroll return to the top after each use?  I reuse the modal and dynamically load the title and body.  But, if I scroll to the bottom, close the modal, open the modal with different content, the modal is scrolled down instead of starting at the top.

Comment: no need of 
.modal{
  display: block !important; /* I added this to see the modal, you don't need this */
}
It directly worked for me.

Comment: JFYI: I fixed my height-problem with `max-height: calc(100vh - 164px)`.

Comment: Hi, calc() won’t work for all browsers. Make sure you are covering the browsers you target and you will be fine.

Comment: Your solution shakes modal. It doesn't look good. When scroll bar appears the modal shrinks a little in width

Comment: The sample web site overflows my screen and isn't usable.

Answer (score 138):

If you're only supporting IE 9 or higher, you can use this CSS that will smoothly scale to the size of the window. You may need to tweak the "200px" though, depending on the height of your header or footer.

```
.modal-body{
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: According to [1] and [2] this is supported by Chrome, Firefox and Safari as well. [1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility [2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Note : This solution makes the popover appears under header or footer depending of the option selected either top or bottom

See this fiddle I created : https://jsfiddle.net/2qeo99k3/4/
Without the css hack it works just fine  just remove it in the fiddle to see it works

Comment: A workaround for the popover can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666828/bootstrap-modal-modal-body-with-overflow-popover-pops-under-header-or-foorter/45666846#45666846

Answer (score 55):

### For Bootstrap versions >= 4.3

Bootstrap 4.3 added new built-in scroll feature to modals. This makes only the **modal-body** content scroll if the size of the content would otherwise make the page scroll. To use it, just add the class **modal-dialog-scrollable** to the same div that has the **modal-dialog** class.

Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
        the<br>quick<br>brown<br>fox<br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it show standard approach

Answer (score 48):

Problem solved with combine solution @carlos calla and @jonathan marston.

```
    /* Important part */
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why do we need overflow-y inside .modal-dialog?

Comment: perfect!also for me it worked liked this.

Comment: I have changed the `modal-body` to this: `max-height: calc(100vh - 250px)`, until this change the modal is still overflow on some smartphone screen (the two i own: iphone 6 and Pixel 4a), and a double scroll is induced

Answer (score 16):

Adding on to [Carlos Calla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2537048/carlos-calla)'s great answer.

The height of .modal-body must be set, BUT you can use media queries to make sure it's appropriate for the screen size.

```
.modal-body{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (min-height: 500px) {
    .modal-body { height: 400px; }
}

@media (min-height: 800px) {
    .modal-body { height: 600px; }
}
```

Comment: Having an assumption that the height will be 400px or greater on a mobile device is faulty. Using width to determine height is not a feasible solution at all. There are too many use cases that would cause this to break.

Comment: @Strawberry he actually used min-height (not min-width) and made sure the height given is less than the min-height in the media-query. In addition, he is only giving an example to his idea because the media query can vary a lot depending on what the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 13):

**Optional**: If you don't want the modal to exceed the window height and use a scrollbar in the .modal-body, you can use this responsive solution.
See a working demo here: http://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc/

```
function setModalMaxHeight(element) {
  this.$element     = $(element);
  this.$content     = this.$element.find('.modal-content');
  var borderWidth   = this.$content.outerHeight() - this.$content.innerHeight();
  var dialogMargin  = $(window).width() > 767 ? 60 : 20;
  var contentHeight = $(window).height() - (dialogMargin + borderWidth);
  var headerHeight  = this.$element.find('.modal-header').outerHeight() || 0;
  var footerHeight  = this.$element.find('.modal-footer').outerHeight() || 0;
  var maxHeight     = contentHeight - (headerHeight + footerHeight);

  this.$content.css({
      'overflow': 'hidden'
  });

  this.$element
    .find('.modal-body').css({
      'max-height': maxHeight,
      'overflow-y': 'auto'
  });
}

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  $(this).show();
  setModalMaxHeight(this);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($('.modal.in').length != 0) {
    setModalMaxHeight($('.modal.in'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

In latest bootstrap version there is a class to make modal body scrollable.

**.modal-dialog-scrollable** to **.modal-dialog**.

[Bootstrap modal link for modal body scrollable content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content)

```html
<!-- Scrollable modal -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old topic but this may help someone else.

I was able to make the body scroll by making the modal-dialog element position fixed.  And since I would never know the exact height of the browser window, I took the information I was sure about, the height of the header and the footer.  I was then able to make the modal-body element's top and bottom margins match those heights.  This then produced the result I was looking for.  I threw together a fiddle to show my work.

also, if you want a full screen dialog just un-comment the width:auto; inside the .modal-dialog.full-screen section.

https://jsfiddle.net/lot224/znrktLej/

And here is the css that I used to modify the bootstrap dialog.

```
.modal-dialog.full-screen {
    position:fixed;
    //width:auto;  // uncomment to make the width based on the left/right attributes.
    margin:auto;                        
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}

.modal-dialog.full-screen .modal-content {
      position:absolute;
      left:10px;
      right:10px;
      top:10px;
      bottom:10px;
}

.modal-dialog.full-screen .modal-content .modal-header {
        height:55px;  // adjust as needed.
}

.modal-dialog.full-screen .modal-content .modal-body {
        overflow-y: auto;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
          margin-top: 55px; // .modal-header height
          margin-bottom: 80px;  // .modal-footer height
}

.modal-dialog.full-screen .modal-content .modal-footer {
        height:80px;  // adjust as needed.
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Or simpler you can put between your tags first, then to the css class.

```
<div style="height: 35px;overflow-y: auto;"> Some text o othre div scroll </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#scroll-wrap {
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Using `max-height` with `vh` as the unit on the `modal-body` or a wrapper div inside of the `modal-body`. This will resize the height of `modal-body` or the wrapping div(in this example) automatically when a user resize the window.

`vh` is length unit representing 1% of the viewport size for viewport height.

[Browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) chart for `vh` unit.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/q3xwr53f/

Answer (score 4):

In your modal body you have to set a height, it can be % vh or calc:

```
modal-body {
    height: 80vh;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

or

```
modal-body {
    height: calc(100vh - 5em);
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

In my case look like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is setting the height to 100% the having the overflow on auto 
hope this will help

```
   <div style="height: 100%;overflow-y: auto;"> Some text o othre div scroll </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple js solution to set modal height proportional to body's height :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('head').append('<style type="text/css">.modal .modal-body {max-height: ' + ($('body').height() * .8) + 'px;overflow-y: auto;}.modal-open .modal{overflow-y: hidden !important;}</style>');
});
```

body's height has to be 100% :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I set modal body height to 80% of body, this can be of course customized.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full Sass rewrite on my website (still building, will add here once it's ready)


It's 100% mobile responsive and fit-to-screen (only when the content is large enough, otherwise the width and height will be fit-to-content, so yes, it's flexible):

- 1.75rem of spacing (equally on 4 sides) on screens larger than 576px (sm)
- 0.5rem of spacing on screens smaller than 576px

For flexible and scrollable `modal-body`, the lines commented with `required` are the minimum codes you need.

```
.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  border: none !important;
}

.modal-dialog {
  height: 100% !important; // required
  margin: 0 0.5rem !important;
  padding: 0.5rem 0 !important;
  overflow-y: initial !important; // required

  @media (min-width: $sm) {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding: 1.75rem 0 !important;
    max-width: initial !important; // overwrite default max-width
    width: fit-content !important; // flexible width
    min-width: 500px !important; // makes it fat enough by default
  }
}

.modal-content {
  max-height: 100% !important; // required
}

.modal-body {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important; // required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boostrap, you can past the tag at the div:
class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; max-height: 500px;"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

add class `modal-dialog-scrollable` if you are using bootstrap 4.5 or higher

else

```
.modal-body{
    height :100%;
    over-flow-y:auto;
}
```