# Making an overlay div (like bootstrap modal or angular dialog) vertically scrollable if data content is not fully shown

Tags: css, angular, dialog, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

How to make an overlay div (like bootstrap modal , or angular dialog) vertically scrollable only if the data content in it is not fully shown in the current window (overflow)?

For example, the dialog content might be fully shown in the default zoom settings, but on zooming in, some content will not appear, so we need to have a vertical scroll bar, how to have it in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing this answer with a rephrased question, as it took me 3 hours to find that answer, so I hope this question & answer will help someone else.

Based on the excellent answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31882320/7588447)

You should use the following css, which will show the vertical scroll bar only if needed

```
.modal-body{
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Note:

The 200px can change based on your website header and footer