# How to add scroll in bootstrap modal?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I created a full screen modal using Bootstrap, when there is too much content I can't scroll. This is my code:

```
.modal-full {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.modal-full .modal-content {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Full [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8XdVt/2390/).

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874001/how-to-put-scrollbar-only-for-modal-body-in-bootstrap-modal-dialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put scrollbar only for modal-body in bootstrap modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874001/how-to-put-scrollbar-only-for-modal-body-in-bootstrap-modal-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootsrap modals have this feature by default.

You just have to make edits to the .modal-dialog and .modal-content classes to make the modal full screen. Check out this [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/RaysOfTheSun/aq9Laaew/240669/) for a working example :)

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`overflow: auto;`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) to `.modal-full`

```css
.modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.modal-full {
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

    .modal-full .modal-content {
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-full">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Test</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h6>Text in a modal</h6>
                                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
                                            <hr>
                                            <h6>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h6>
                                            <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
                                            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
                                            <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css with this

```
.modal-full .modal-content {
   min-height: 100vh;
   max-height: 100vh;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```