# Modal body between header and footer to be scrollable to the end dynamically

Tags: css

I have this modal with header and footer. I want the body to be scrollable as the content is very long but the height of the body should end where the footer starts.

Currently the body height is overlapping the footer and thus you can't see the content on the bottom of body.

I don't know the height of the device. How can I make the body to be dynamic between header and footer and scroll from top to bottom and be able to see all elements?

PS: the header height is dynamic so I don't know the value but the bottom height can be set

[image]

```css
body {
  width:450px;
  background:#f4f4f4;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.modal {
  visibility:visible;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  width:inherit;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.modal-header {
  background: gray;
  padding:20px;
}

.modal-body {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background:#FFF;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
  <p>
  content
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class='modal'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
      <input type='text'/>
      <input type='text'/>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>d</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>too long</div>
      <div>LAST VISIBLE ELEMENT</div>

    </div>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
      <button>
      click
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you clearly said that bottom height can be set.

Assume a height to the modal-footer and set the height for the body using `calc` property

so it will take the entire height except the height for the footer content.

Try this

```css
    body {
      width:450px;
      background:#f4f4f4;
      margin:0 auto;
    }

    .modal {
      visibility:visible;
      bottom: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      background: #fff;
      width:inherit;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    }

    .modal-header {
      background: gray;
      padding:20px;
    }

    .modal-body {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      margin-bottom:50px;
      height: calc(100% - 100px);/*Added height here*/
    }

    .modal-footer {
      display: block;
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      background:#FFF;
      bottom: 0;
      height: auto;
      position: fixed;
      width:100%;
      padding:10px;
      
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <div>
      <p>
      content
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class='modal'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
          <input type='text'/>
          <input type='text'/>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>a</div>
          <div>b</div>
          <div>c</div>
          <div>d</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>too long</div>
          <div>LAST VISIBLE ELEMENT</div>

        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
          <button>
          click
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to this answer
[How to put scrollbar only for modal-body in bootstrap modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874001/how-to-put-scrollbar-only-for-modal-body-in-bootstrap-modal-dialog)

```
.modal-dialog{
   overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
   height: 250px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gene, I know I can set the height myself but as mentioned in the post I would prefer some dynamic approach. I believe it should be possible to do this with flex or something else~